# Windows Workflow a good fit for non programming end users?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

Is WF4 suited for end-user situations?  For example, I have a application framework built that my customers can use.  It's very basic.  I want them to have the ability to create their own business rules and work flows using their data.

Would I (the developer) have to code and design many workflows for my end users or is there a way they can do their own in a somewhat, non-technical manner?

Or should I start looking for a way to do my own pseudo-workflow framework?

Thanks

Comment: The work flow designer can be hosted in a web application allowing for work flows to be created and managed by anyone but I think you will find that you may have to create custom activities related to business needs. But once you have all the activities you need there is nothing really technical about creating basic work flows in the hosted designer utilizing custom or built in activities.

Comment: This should be community Wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your end users aren't developers/programmers, it is certainly not for them. WF is a lot like visually programming business rules and processes but doesn't make it easy for the "average Joe". If you want some type of interface for them to set business rules, I wouldn't choose it. That's my two cents.

Comment: Not knowing much about WF, I was really thinking the same thing.  Everything I saw about it really screams developer focused.  Which is fine.  I will look else where for customer-focused solutions.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you host the designer in your own application and provide the business focused custom activities you can make a good user focused application; **provided** that is your end users are **familiar** with concepts like **flow charts** and **business process** design.

I would say if the target user is a business professional then its probably a good fit.
If your hoping to provide this functionality to a less business oriented audience then I would agree with Jlafay, its not for the "average Joe".

Its perhaps a narrow band of ideal target users, but I suspect not that uncommon as users of much software.